# Time complexity of for loop nested in a while loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, time-complexity

I have the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
boolean dataAssegnata = false;
        
while(!dataAssegnata) {
            
    data.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            
    for(int giorno : giorniConsegna)
        if(giorno == data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            dataAssegnata = true;
            System.out.println(s.format(data.getTime()).toString());
        }
}
```

I will use it to assign a delivery date to an order. `int[] giorniConsegna` contains the days of the week for the order delivery as integers (monday = 2, tuesday = 3 ...). I wrote this code for a project and I have to calculate its time complexity and I'm having troubles with the `while` loop.

If I'm right, the time complexity of the `for` loop is `O(n)`, but I can't figure out what is the overall time complexity. I guess it is `O(m*n)`, where `m` is the worst-case scenario of the `while` loop (that will run `m` times), but I am not so sure about that.

Am I right or is the solution different?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `O(n^2)` because the number of times the while loop will run depends on the integer array `giorniConsegna`. Worst case scenario for while loop is `O(n)`.

Comment: Yes, the number of times the while loop will run depends on the integer array `giorniConsegna`, but I don't think it's worst case scenario is `O(n)`. For example, `giorniConsegna` can contain the numbers representing the days from monday to saturday, and in this case the while loop will run 2 times in the worst case scenario (order received on saturday and assigned in monday).

Comment: You are talking about one case, which is not the worst case. Worst case is when all the elements of the array needs to be traversed in order to get the condition `giorno == data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`, which is when the while loop will end